# Usage of Bang (!) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, source, source-code

I am reading the bash source code, and the [BNF grammar](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/src/bash/bash.bnf) for bash would be:

```
<pipeline_command> ::= <pipeline>
                    |  '!' <pipeline>
                    |  <timespec> <pipeline>
                    |  <timespec> '!' <pipeline>
                    |  '!' <timespec> <pipeline>

<pipeline> ::=
          <pipeline> '|' <newline_list> <pipeline>
       |  <command>
```

Does this means `!` command is a kind of pipe too.

`! ls` works， however it's the same as `ls`.

`! time ls` works too.

That's quite different to `|` pipe.

How to use `!` in bash? Is it a pipe?

Comment: The output of `! ls` and `ls` are the same; the exit status are different.

Answer (score 11):

From the bash manual: "If the reserved word ! precedes a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of the exit status"

You are misreading the grammar. What the grammar says is that you can put a ! in front of a pipeline, not replace | with a !.

Answer (score 7):

The exclamation point just logically reverses the return code of the command/pipeline (see e.g. [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html)):

```
if true ;    then echo 'this prints' ; fi
if ! false ; then echo 'this also prints' ; fi
if ! true ;  then echo 'this does not print' ; fi
```

The return code of a pipeline is (usually) just the return code of the last command, so the bang inverts that:

```
if ! true | false ; then echo 'again, this also prints' ; fi
```

As it happens, I can't see that BNF file in the Bash source distribution, and the quoted grammar isn't exactly accurate, as Bash does accept multiple bangs since Bash 4.2 (released in 2011):

```
if ! ! true ; then echo 'this prints too' ; fi
```

That's not standard, though, and e.g. zsh and Dash croak at it.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a pipeline to be *one* or more commands means a single command is also a pipeline, albeit one that doesn't actually involve a pipe. The benefit is that `!` as a negation operator doesn't have to be defined separately for commands and pipelines; it need only be defined as applying to a pipeline.

In `! cmd1 | cmd2`, the `!` negates the exit status of the entire pipeline, not just the single command `cmd1`. The exit status of a pipeline, by default, is the exit status of the right-most command.

---

Likewise, a *list* is one more pipelines joined by `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`. Thus, a single pipeline is also a list, and a single command is also a list. Then, when a command like `if` is defined as taking a list between the `if` and `then` keywords, this automatically includes single commands and single pipelines as part of the definition of a command.

- A list consisting of two pipelines (one of which only consists of one command):

  ```
  if IFS= read -r response && echo "$response" | grep foo; then
  ```
- A list consisting of a single pipeline:

  ```
  if echo "$foo" | grep foo; then
  ```
- A list consisting of  single pipeline (which itself contains only a single command):

  ```
  if true; then
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points to add to what the other answers said:

- As noted (indirectly) by [chepner’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406973/80216#407124),
  the `!` operator is defined as an optional prefix
  to the `<pipeline_command>` syntactic element,
  rather than to `<command>`. 
  This has the consequence that you cannot say

  ```
    cmd1 | ! cmd2
  ```

  or

  ```
  ! cmd1 | ! cmd2
  ```

  You can only negate the exit status of an “entire pipeline”. 
  As chepner pointed out, a “pipeline” can be a single command,
  so you can do things like

  ```
  ! cmd1 && ! cmd2; ! cmd3 || ! cmd4
  ```

  but that’s silly. 
  The `!` before `cmd2` does nothing whatsoever;
  the `!` before `cmd4` affects only the value of `$?`
  at the end of the command,
  and the other two can be eliminated by exchanging the AND and the OR:

  ```
    cmd1  ||  cmd2;   cmd3  &&  cmd4
  ```

  Similarly, `while ! cmd` can be replaced with `until cmd`.
- A `<pipeline>` preceded by a `!` becomes a `<pipeline_command>` —
  a different syntactic element. 
  Therefore, it is not valid to say

  ```
  ! ! cmd1
  ```

  unlike arithmetic expansion,
  where things like `$((! ! value))`
  and `$((! ! ! value))` are valid.
- Be advised that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) defines the same grammar,
  but uses different element names. 
  The BNF in the question appears in POSIX as

  ```
  pipeline         :      pipe_sequence
                   | Bang pipe_sequence

  pipe_sequence    :                             command
                   | pipe_sequence '|' linebreak command
  ```

  where `Bang` is a `%token` with the value `'!'`.